# Get Multiple Columns as Single Column with Distinct Values

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm attempting to get a list of distinct values from multiple columns in a table. I've tried a few things without success including `CONCAT_WP`. I'm wondering if anything like this is possible.

The table looks something like this:

```
station   | 6am-10am          | 10am-12pm         | 12pm-3pm
----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------
1         | The Bob Show      | Local Programming | Paid Programming   
2         | Local Programming | The Bob Show      | Local Programming
3         | Local Programming | John Doe Show     | John Doe Show
4         | John Doe Show     | Paid Programming  | The Bob Show
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the distinct show names from multiple columns. While this looks simple enough, I'm dealing with 26 columns so I'm trying to find a solution that doesn't require me to repeat a line of code 26 times.

I need it to return distinct show names, one per row, if possible.

```
Local Programming
Paid Programming
The Bob Show
John Does Show
```

Comment: That looks more like a spreadsheet than a table. See normalisation.

Comment: What's your criteria for the values?

Comment: Definitely normalise your data, you'll be glad you did now and definitely in the long run.

Comment: Join the same table 3 times to itself using station (ie, table1  t1 inner join table1 t2...) and then do a union query.  try it.